# How Can I Set the Interpolation of a F-Curve via Python? (Blender)

Tags: python, math, interpolation, blender

I have a Scale F-Curve of an Object and what I need Is to set its interpolation as **CUBIC** for example.

What is the simpliest and the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a long winding path to the fcurves ;), but once you get there it is quick to work with.

Starting with the active object, you want to go to the fcurves

```
fc = bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves
```

Other fcurves can be found in similar paths eg for material nodes it is

```
fc = mat.node_tree.animation_data.action.fcurves
```

fcurves is a list of all curves, it is usually easiest to use [find](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html#bpy.types.ActionFCurves.find) to get the curve you want (the index values 0,1,2 match x,y,z) unless you want to loop through and change them all.

```
loc_x_curve = fc.find('scale', index=0)
```

Then each curve is a list of [keyframe](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html) items that have their own interpolation setting.

```
for k in loc_x_curve.keyframe_points:
    # k.co[0] is the frame number
    # k.co[1] is the keyed value
    k.interpolation = 'CUBIC'
    k.easing = 'EASE_IN'
```

Comment: And if I want to set the interpolation only between two keyframes?

Comment: `if k[0] == 24 or k[0] == 25: k.interpolation = 'CUBIC'`

Comment: You only need to set the interpolation mode of the first of the two keyframes. Otherwise, you could not set different modes between two consecutive segments. This means: `if k[0] == 24: k.interpolation = 'CUBIC'` would be correct.

Answer (score -2):

Try using SciPy,
for example , the following would work:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=11, endpoint=True)
>>> y = np.cos(-x**2/9.0)
>>> f = interp1d(x, y)
>>> f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
>>> xnew = np.linspace(0, 10, num=41, endpoint=True)
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f(xnew), '-', xnew, f2(xnew), '--')
>>> plt.legend(['data', 'linear', 'cubic'], loc='best')
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: It's very complicated, isn't there a simplest way to do it?